# How to set a portal page title from within a portlet?

Tags: portlet, websphere-portal, page-title

How can I set a portal page title from within a portlet programatically? I'm using Websphere Portal 6.1. I tried the option from the below link. But I didn't work. Does anyone has any idea?

http://wpcertification.blogspot.in/2010/09/changing-title-of-portal-page.html
http://wpcertification.blogspot.in/2010/09/enable-two-phase-rendering-in-portlet.html

Comment: Can you post the code you tried? That blog is typically a very reliable source and I'd be surprised if something from him didn't work.

Comment: What type of portlet is it? If it is based on JSR 168, then the above link will not work. It has to be based on JSR 286

Comment: @NickRoth I tried the code provided in the forum. I could see my logger messages in my logs but the title is not changing.

Comment: @Apps It is a JSR286 portlet. The code within the doHeaders method is executing. I can see the logger messages in my log. But the title is not changing.

Comment: Is there multiple title elements in the head section of your page?

Comment: @NickRoth No. There is only one title element.